# Pagination Re-Write Rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What ReWrite rule can I put in the .htaccess file to make

```
domain.com/directory/index.php?page=$page
```

rewrite into

```
domain.com/directory/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^directory/([0-9]+)/?$  directory/index.php?page=$1     [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://domain.com/directory/PageNumber`

To:

`http://domain.com/directory/index.php?page=PageNumber`

`directory` and `index.php` are assumed to be fixed strings.

For permanent redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

Comment: It means the redirection is supposed to be permanent, but in your case that aspect is irrelevant as the substitution URLs are generated dynamically. The important difference is visibility, it is displayed in the browser's address bar, while the other one (Implied with the `L` flag) is internal, not shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule /directory/(\d+) /directory/index.php?page=$1
```